# how do i use multiple <content> tag in single polymer element?

Tags: html, dom, polymer-1.0

I am trying to access same data in single element for two times, one for desktop navigation and one for responsive navigation(drawer toolbar). For this I use two content tags but it takes only one. In this this case what to do

```
<app-drawer-layout force-narrow>

  <app-drawer id="drawer">

    <app-toolbar></app-toolbar>

    <!-- Nav on mobile: side nav menu -->
    <paper-menu selected="{{selected}}" attr-for-selected="name">
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{items}}">
        <paper-item name="{{item}}">{{item}}</paper-item>
      </template>
    </paper-menu>

  </app-drawer>

  <app-header-layout>
    <app-header class="main-header">

      <app-toolbar>
        <paper-icon-button class="menu-button" icon="menu" drawer-toggle hidden$="{{wideLayout}}"></paper-icon-button>
      </app-toolbar>

      <app-toolbar class="tabs-bar" hidden$="{{!wideLayout}}">
        <!-- Nav on desktop: tabs -->
        <paper-tabs selected="{{selected}}" attr-for-selected="name" bottom-item>
          <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{items}}">
            <paper-tab name="{{item}}">{{item}}</paper-tab>
          </template>
        </paper-tabs>
      </app-toolbar>

    </app-header>
  </app-header-layout>

</app-drawer-layout>

<iron-media-query query="min-width: 600px" query-matches="{{wideLayout}}"></iron-media-query>
```

Polymer code:

```
Polymer({
  is: 'x-app',
  properties: {
    selected: {
      type: String,
      value: 'Item One'
    },
    wideLayout: {
      type: Boolean,
      value: false,
      observer: 'onLayoutChange',
    },
    items: {
      type: Array,
      value: function() {
        return ['Item One', 'Item Two', 'Item Three', 'Item Four'];
      }
    }
  },
  onLayoutChange: function(wide) {
    var drawer = this.$.drawer;
    if (wide && drawer.opened) {
      drawer.opened = false;
    }
  }
});
```

I have this type of code. What should I do to add menu element without using array. I want to add them separately from index at both app-header and app-drawer. but in index it should written one time as shown below.

```
   <wt-header logo="logo url" enable-menu="true" enable-topbar="false">
        <wt-menu>
        <wt-tab name="TabName" action="http://example.com/action" />
        <wt-tab name="TabName1" action="http://example.com/action2" />
        <wt-tab name="TabName3" action="http://example.com/action3" />
        </wt-menu>
    </wt-header>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to provide it twice. `<content>` doesn't "produce" what you pass to an element, it just projects the content - `<content>` is just a slot where the passed content is shown.

If you want to provide it twice, then you need to add a `select=".some"` to at least one `<content>` to define what part of the projected content (the one that matches the selector `.some`) should be projected to this `<content select=".some">` and what content should be projected to the other `<content>` element.

An alternative approach is to pass the content within a `<template>...</template>` and then use [templatizer](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/Polymer.Templatizer) to append the content of the template multiple times. This is for example how `<template is="dom-repeat">` or [`<iron-list>`](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-list/blob/master/iron-list.html#L1029) are doing it

Comment: Thanks, I am trying it.

Comment: See also https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom#dom-distribution